# automate whatsapp application using python

Tags: python, automation, whatsapp

is there anyway to send msg with attachment from WhatsApp application (not web browser)
i tried the command below  but it just type the msg without sending it , and can not find the way to add attachment

```
subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "start whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXX^&text=my message"],stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

** i just prefer application over web browser because it is more stable from prespective of WhatsApp Qr login, and it's more faster

and thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
from keyboard import press
import subprocess
    
msg = 123456

subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "start whatsapp://send?phone=*******^&text="+str(msg)], shell=True)
        
time.sleep(5)
press('enter')
```

Comment: by using native app, subprocess can draft your msg but for automatically send the draft you have to import and use keyboard library !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers (if there are any).